# How to add mule flow developed in project to other mule project

Tags: java, mule

I want to add a mule flow developed in one project to another project i.e wanted to use the flow created in one project in another project like flow reference.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understood your requirement correctly, Your trying to access one mule flow that resides in one project from another project mule flow.

If yes, then you can't use mule flow reference component to achieve this instead you can VM component.

Mule introduced concept of Domains in mule run time version 3.5 and mule anypoint studio with run time version 3.6.

With Domains concept you can access flows across projects using VM component. Go through the below Mule documentation link that will clearly tell you on how to

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/shared-resources

1) How to create Domain application.

2) How to create Shared components in Domain.

3) Creating application that uses shared components in Domains.

4) Deployment of Domains etc ..

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your projects via Maven and package reusable flows. Mule can then use any of these flows imported on the classpath: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/modularizing-your-configuration-files-for-team-development